# SQL statement syntax error - using AND twice

Tags: php, sql, pdo

Somehow I am stuck with my SQL code. I want to check 2 things in one statement but I guess my syntax is wrong, could you please help me?

Here is my code:

```
($statement = $db->prepare("SELECT t_date,t_free FROM t_termins WHERE (t_date Between ? AND ?) AND (t_free= ?) "));
    $statement->bind_param("ssi", $datefrom, $dateto,0);
    $statement->execute();
```

Comment: your sql syntax if fine, look somewhere else....

Comment: how I know if it sfine?, it does not work

Comment: You could try where t_date >= ? and t_date <= ? and t_free = ? (but as M.Ali pointed out, your current syntax is correct)

Comment: You should show the error message and tag the question with the database you are using.

Comment: Is this PDO or mysqli?